# Resizing an image w.r.t to its height and width

Tags: imagemagick

I need to resize an image so that if its height is smaller than its width, I'll set its height and vice versa. 
I wonder if there's a way doing this directly from the command line. Using '^' operator behaves just the opposite (or I could not succeed using it for my purpose).
Thanks for replies.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11218935/85950) for a way to do this from the command line using `identify` and some bash logic.