# ImageMagick resizing to an abstract rectangle

Tags: imagemagick

I'm given an image of unknown size.  I want to shrink it such that it will fit in *either* 640x480 or 480x640, preserving aspect ratio.  I want the image to shrink the minimum amount (e.g. the result should be the maximum size which fits in either 640x480 or 480x640).

For example, if I have a 800x800 image, it should shrink to 480x480.  If I have a 500x1000 image, it should shrink to 320x640.  Similarly, 1000x500 should become 640x320.

Can I do this in ImageMagick in one command?  No cropping should occur, and the aspect ratio of the original image should be preserved.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing an image w.r.t to its height and width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003490/resizing-an-image-w-r-t-to-its-height-and-width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to resize an image without cropping and preserving the aspect ratio, but I don't think that you'll be able to achieve your either/or in a single command.

From the [geometry specification docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry), resizing an overlarge image to 640x480 is easy:

```
convert input.png -resize 640x480> output.png
```

That will only resize if necessary, won't crop, and will preserve the aspect ratio.

Depending on your input images, you might be able to use the area operator:

```
convert input.png -resize $((640*480))@ output.png
```

But that will only work if all the input images already have either a 4/3 or 3/4 aspect ratio.

I think your best bet is a short shell script:

```
wider_than_tall=`identify -format %w/%h input.png`
if (( $wider_than_tall )); then
  convert input.png -resize 640x480> output.png
else
  convert input.png -resize 480x640> output.png
fi
```